# Connect Java to MariaDB in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jdbc, mariadb

I need to connect to my database but I keep getting an error that says "driver not found".

I have added **mariadb-java-client-3.0.8.jar** jar file and it is still not working.

[image: image of the jar file in classpath]

And this works pretty well on NetBeans, but I need to know how to fix that in VScode IDE. Do you know what I am missing?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/cpit305-project", "root", "");
            System.out.println("working");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/cpit305-project

Comment: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));` (as the first line of your code)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your connection string is correct. Then the database name avoids the use of dashes (`-`).

The same code works fine for me.

[image]

Download the connection package [here](https://mariadb.com/downloads/connectors/connectors-data-access/java8-connector).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same problem. I solved it by exporting classpath into my .zshrc file.

Add this to you shell:
export CLASSPATH=/path/mysql-connector-java-ver.jar:$CLASSPATH

Comment: Using the `CLASSPATH` environment variable is almost always the wrong choice. Most methods of running Java code will even ignore it, and if they don't you might run into problems because the classpath contains unexpected or incompatible libraries.

Comment: Edit to format properly